# Gunfire/Explosion Went Off

Tags: meaning, grammar, usage

I have a question about the phrase "*go off*".  According to most dictionaries, "*go off*" could be used like this:

> 1. ***The gun*** went off.
> 2. ***A bomb*** went off.

, where both "gun" and "bomb" are devices.  But, on the web, examples like the following are found:

> 3. ***Gunfire*** went off.
> 4. ***An explosion*** went off.

, where "*gunfire*" and "*explosion*" are actions.  Dictionaries seem to only allow sentences 1 and 2, but not 3 and 4.

What do native speakers think?  Are sentences 3 & 4 standard English?

Comment: My feeling is that it's understandable but not standard.  If you compare *gun went off/gunfire went off* you'll see that the *gunfire* version is vanishingly rare: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gun+went+off%2Cgunfire+went+off&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgun%20went%20off%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgunfire%20went%20off%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Isn't it remarkable how so many attestations of "gunfire went off" (indluding *a series of gunfire went off*) occur in pulp fiction? https://www.google.com/search?q=%22gunfire%20went%20off%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, I ave see worse writing... but not very often.

Comment: 3 and 4 are acceptable but clunky. 1 and 2 are better and sound more natural.

Comment: In strict theory, you are wholly correct; “Gunfire…” and “An explosion” don’t “go off” but that’s not how most people think or speak.

Please consider instead, “a fast speed…” when despite common usage, there cannot really be such a thing. 

A *high* speed” is logical. A *fast* speed actually means a “speedy speed”.

Then, are we interested in linguistic rules, or everyday use of language?

Answer (score 1):

We use the term '[go off](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/go_off)' about a change of state: something that happens just once. At one moment the gun contains powder and a bullet: the next it contains only smoke. The same is true of bombs, fireworks, foodstuffs (albeit rather slower). For an alarm clock, it descibes the moment when the clock **starts** ringing. If a person goes off something, it means that they stop liking something... a state change from liking to not.

Because it is a state change, it works for a single shot from a rifle, pistol or shotgun, but the term does not fit comfortably with the continuous discharge of an automatic weapon.

Gunfire is a continuous activity and so, like the automatic weapon, it doesn't sit naturally with **going off**.... unless, like the alarm clock, you choose to regard it as the moment that the gunfire started. So, gunfire going off is understandable, and [it is used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gun%20went%20off%2C%20gunfire%20went%20off&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgun%20went%20off%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgunfire%20went%20off%3B%2Cc0), but it does not sound natural.

An explosion is already a state change: it sounds wrong to talk about a state change of a state change. An explosion going off [does occur](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bomb%20went%20off%2C%20explosive%20went%20off%2Cexplosion%20went%20off&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbomb%20went%20off%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexplosive%20went%20off%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexplosion%20went%20off%3B%2Cc0), but again it does not sound natural.

Answer (score 0):

Both 3 & 4 are acceptable and understandable

> Gunfire suddenly **went off** in the distance.
>   *the sudden sound of gunfire was heard in the distance*
>
> An explosion **went off** and set the factory on fire.
>   *an explosion set the factory on fire*

Comment: More accurately, it's the bombs and guns that *go off* although gunfire and explosions are often said to do so.

Comment: Understandable I guess, but I don't know about "acceptable".  The gunfire doesn't "go off", the gunfire is the act the gun of going off.  It's like saying "the sound made a noise."

Comment: I like "gunfire erupted"

Answer (score 0):

*The gun…* or *A bomb went off* are fine and it doesn’t matter that they’re devices. People can *go off* in much the same way.
*Gunfire…* or *An explosion went off* are perfectly understandable but wholly unidiomatic, tautological and largely ungrammatical.
*Gunfire* is not something independent: it’s the result of a gun going off.
*An explosion* is not something independent: it’s the result of a bomb going off.
By the way no; none of them are actions.
*Firing a gun* is an action and it isn’t *gunfire*. *Gunfire* is a noun.
*A bomb exploding* is an action and it isn’t *an explosion*. An *explosion* is a noun.

Comment: They're just careless, unless the speaker wants argue about it. In that case, they're wrong.
Idiomatically *The gun went off* is correct and *Gunfire went off* wrong but that’s because strictly, *The gun was fired* which makes *gunfire was fired* tautological; it clearly repeats itself.
Your *explosion* is very much less clear but still, broadly similar.

Answer (score 0):

Gunfire and explosions aren't actions, they're things. Therefore, all examples are correct

However, you can't strictly say

> Exploding went off

> The firing of a gun went off

Though some people may say this, it is very informal slang, so don't use it